# Plotting the data in a time-series manner for multiple attributes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to visualize the data in Jupyter notebook based in the shape of time-series. The data is representing the sales of a store for each month of years 2013, 2014 and 2015. So, each year should be represented by a line, where x axis is the months and y axis shows the sales. Even though, I can select the data in a table, I have difficulties plotting them on a time-series chart. What is the best way to actually plot this data in Jupyter notebook?

The data looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
monthlySales['sales'].unstack().plot()
```

[image]